# How to make Bootstrap 3 non-responsive for small .container?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

For whole site there is very easy with [Bootstrap3 instructions](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)

But what if I had a small container, e.g. 400px and need to turn off responsiveness inside this container? I need fully functional Dropdown in my navbar, but when responsive is on, dropdowns in small containers are not like "popups", they opens inside navbar and stretch them out.

Also, I can't compile my own bootstrap version without responsive styles, because I need to use CDN (cdnjs).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question/problem properly, then define `.container` class as below in custom stylesheet. (assume that you wish to ha max width of 400px screen. change it accordingly.)

```
@media screen and (min-width:401px) { 
   .container { 
     max-width:400px;
   }
}
```

And then use `col-xs-xx` - (xx is column number) classes only.

Comment: No, that's not helping. It's just a fixed max-width for .container. I need Dropdown and other stuff without responsive changes, not a col-* grid.

Comment: then download customized bootstrap from http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ . you have to utilize Media queries breakpoints according to your needs.

Comment: Then I can't use CDN! :)